# Как вывести древовидную структуру в Django

Tags: python, django, jinja2, дерево, шаблонизаторы

Есть модель комментариев:

```py
class Comments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Articles,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='Статья',
        related_name='Comments'
    )
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        verbose_name='Ответ на',
        related_name='Replies'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Пользователь',
        related_name='Comments'
    )
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_datetime = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=24,
        default='published'
    )
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ": " + str(self.article) + "[{}]".format(self.comment_datetime)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комменатрий'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Написал функцию для получения комментариев к статье в древовидной структуре:

```py
def getCommentsTree(src=Articles.objects.get(id=1)):
    class Tree:

        def __init__(self, elem):
            self.body = elem
            self.heirs = []

        def __str__(self):
            if isinstance(self.body, Comments):
                print(self.body.comment)
            elif isinstance(self.body, str):
                print(self.body)
            else:
                print(self.body.__class__.__name__)

        body = None
        heirs = list()

        def append(self, elem):
            self.heirs.append(Tree(elem))

        def recapp(self, elem):
            if isinstance(elem, QuerySet):
                for i in elem.all():
                    self.recapp(Tree(i))
            elif isinstance(elem, Tree):
                self.append(elem.body)
                for i in elem.body.Replies.all():
                    self.heirs[-1].recapp(Tree(i))
            else:
                raise TypeError("Must be Tree or QuerySet")

        def recprint(self, layer=0, show_root=True):
            if show_root:
                print("-" * layer, end='')
                if isinstance(self.body, str):
                    print(self.body)
                else:
                    print(self.body.comment)
            else:
                layer -= 1
            for i in self.heirs:
                i.recprint(layer + 1)

    return Tree("ROOT").recapp(Comments.objects.filter(article=src, reply_to=None))
```

И вывод в консоль через `recprint()` работает как надо, а вот с тем, как сделать вывод на страницу статьи, у меня возникли проблемы - я даже не знаю, с чего начать. Сначала появилсь идея как-то использовать самописные теги для шаблонизатора, но до этого я сталкивался лишь с простыми тегами, которые просто возвращают значение, так что тут тоже не очень представляю, как сделать и через них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекурсивное включение - наше всё.

article_comments.html:

```html
{% for tree in tree.heirs %}
<div class="comment" id="comment-{{tree.body.id}}">
    <div class="comment-user">
        <div class="avatar">
            {% if tree.body.user.profile.avatar %}
            <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{tree.body.user.profile.avatar}}" alt="Аватар">
            {% else %}
            <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/avatars/default.png" alt="Аватар">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <h4 class="username {{tree.body.user.groups.all.0.name}}">{{tree.body.user.username}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="comment-body">
        {{tree.body.comment}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="replies">
    {% if tree.heirs %}
        {% include "includes/article_comment.html" %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

style.css:

```css
...
...
...
div.comment{
    display: table;
}

div.comment-user{
    display: table-row;
}

div.comment-user .avatar{
    display: table-cell;
}

div.comment-user .avatar img{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

div.comment{
    display: table-cell;
    /*border: solid 1px #5a6268;*/
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div.comment-body{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
div.comments .replies{
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

ну а в article.html пишем так:

```html
<div class="comments">
    {% include "includes/article_comment.html" %}
</div>
```

В views.py в response добавляем ключ `'tree'` со значением `getCommentsTree(Articles.objects.get(id=pk))`

А то, как разбираться с самописной структурой, к моему удивлению, шаблонизатор придумывает сам. Более того, в views.py даже не нужно импортировать класс Tree.

Результат:
[image: Результат]